# Does it make any sense to grate the radish on a grater without peeling its skin?

Tags: grating, radish

Does the radish automatically get rid of it's skin when grated on the grater? OR for safety reasons is it better to peel the skin off the radish before grating?

By radish I mean this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daikon

Comment: Do you usually peel radishes? I never have. (Are we talking about the same kind of radish? In the US we have primarily [something like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:210704_radieschen-raphanus-sativus-marktware_1-640x480.jpg).)

Comment: @Jefromi See edit. :) BTW, I never saw your kind of radishes? Do they (your and mine) taste different?

Comment: Ah, okay! You can also find daikon here but it's usually called daikon, in my experience. And yes, they're fairly different. Daikon has a milder flavor; the little pink ones have a stronger sharp, peppery flavor, along with a little of a flavor that's also in horseradish and mustard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daikon peel is edible. I believe it does have a somewhat different flavor (stronger? I don't have one around to try) than the rest of the root, so you might want to try a bit before you include the peel in a dish. You'll also have to wash a bit more carefully to make sure you don't leave any dirt on. And the skin is tougher, but if you're grating perpendicular to it, you'll end up with small enough pieces that it shouldn't be a problem.